# Nginx localhost multi site downloads php files instead of executing

Tags: nginx, php, localhost

I have multi sites in my web root (/var/www), for example site1, site2, etc. and I configured Nginx as below:

```
## PHP-FPM Servers ##
upstream localhost-php-fpm {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {

    server_name localhost;
    
    listen 80;
    
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    location /site1/web {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/web/index.php?$args;
    }
    
    location /site2/web {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/web/index.php?$args;
    }
    
    # pass to php-fpm
    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass localhost-php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 15000;         
    }

}
```

When I request for root of a site for example `http://localhost/site1/web`, a download window opens to download index.php. But When I request for some path `http://localhost/site1/web/dashboard` every thing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `try_files` directive to your last `location` block.

Comment: Hello @Ricaz, can you explain more? Which directive and how should try_files be?

Comment: I add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to `location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {` block, but it doesn't work. `index.php` of every site is in `web` folder of that site.